# Download from a private Github repo

Tags: git, bash, github, wget

I am trying to reduce the footprint of our projects on the production server. I am not an expert for such operational stuff but I came up with the following bash script.

```
VERSION=$1
rm -rf pydata

# clone the entire github repository. This is kind of inefficient as we delete the .git folder in a moment
git clone git@github.com:tt/pydata.git

cd pydata

# checkout the correct version
git checkout $VERSION --

# Print the version into a txt file
echo $VERSION > version.txt

# Build the Python environment using conda
make build

# delete a bunch of files not needed on the server but contained in the git repository (documentation etc.)
xargs rm -rf < delete.txt
rm delete.txt

# back into the folder
cd ..
```

Is there an elegant way to find the latest tag (in case the user is not providing the desired tag (in $1))?

My little research indicates that rather cloning the entire git rep and then deleting the .git folder it would be better to have git archive available which is not supported by github?

The alternative would be using wget on the tar.gz archives? This would avoid the download of the .git folder but seems to create all sorts of extra headache as it doesn't support SSH out of the box?

thanks

Comment: I would advice to use releases from a seperate "release" branch. There is also an API from Github to get the latest one: https://developer.github.com/v3/repos/releases/#get-the-latest-release

Answer (score 1):

To get the latest git tag you can use `git describe`.

```
if [ ''$VERSION = '' ]
then
  VERSION=$(git describe)
fi
```